# YAML parser in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parsing, yaml

Are there any YAML parsers or YAML Serialization libs in Delphi?

Comment: this looks interesting: https://github.com/exilon/QuickLib - see Quick.YAML and Quick.YAML.Serializer there. More on the library at https://blogs.embarcadero.com/quicklib-is-a-powerful-third-party-library-for-delphi-which-can-boost-productivity/

Answer (score 8):

I have recently started a Delphi-YAML project on BitBucket:

https://bitbucket.org/OCTAGRAM/delphi-yaml

At least, I've got something running, but there are many tests missing and there are probably many bugs hiding.

Comment: https://github.com/ashumkin/delphi-yaml - an alive mirror

Comment: https://github.com/neslib/Neslib.Yaml - another one a C-library wrapper for Delphi, for other library

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about a full YAML implementation, but [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (a subset) is getting pretty popular and there are even some Delphi libraries listed on the JSON site.  Delphi 2009 is even using (a slightly modified version of?) JSON in DataSnap.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson

http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6

http://sourceforge.net/projects/is-webstart/

Comment: I don't know much about inner working of DataSnap but the reason why I need YAML lib is because I am assigned a task to write a client software that communicates with a Server which is written in Python and this Server demands that all data exchange be done through YAML!

If there is a lib available that would be great and I will be able to develop the client in Delphi or other wise I will have to spend a few sleepless nights Mastering Python.

Comment: @YogiYang007 After these years, did you find a library or wrote your own? anything could be shared? thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be it is high time to implement a YAML parser in Delphi...

Copy code from PyYAML (but Python is a dynamically typed language)

Or take a look at SnakeYAML which is written in a statically typed language (Java)

Answer (score 1):

Free Pascal also has some json libs.

I garbled up something like this to interface with PHP once. Here is the code:

http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/phpser.zip

Note that it is more proof of concept than an usable lib.

Answer (score 1):

This open source C# YAML parser looks like it could be a starting point for a Delphi implementation:

[YamlDotNet - A .NET library for parsing and emitting YAML](http://yamldotnet.sourceforge.net/)