# How can I read from YAML config file using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parsing, yaml

I'm trying to read from .cfg file I don't know enough about YAML, but I want to do this:

My config file its using YAML.

```
   
Residences:
  luchidv:
    EnterMessage: Estas entrando la residencia %residence de %owner.
    BlackList:
      Type: BLACKLIST
      ItemList: []
    LeaveMessage: Ahora estas saliendo de %residence.
    IgnoreList:
      Type: IGNORELIST
      ItemList: []
    Areas:
      main:
        X1: -1560
        Y1: 99
            Z1: 1457
```

So, how can Delphi parse the content of that config file?
I need to read the value by example:

```
Line:13
X1: -1560
```

Any idea how to do it?

I have been searching about and I found this:

http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML

Thanks

Comment: When I needed to do this, I wrote a wrapper around LibYAML.

Answer (score 2):

Just Google for "Delphi yaml parser" and sixth result is https://bitbucket.org/OCTAGRAM/delphi-yaml/wiki/Home

The first result is even better though: [YAML parser in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824257/yaml-parser-in-delphi)

Comment: I checked that before, but the problem with this one at least for me its: i dont know how to install or use it

Comment: Very strange problem, @Martini002 . Are you firstcomer to Delphi? Just add directory to Unit search path, use Yaml unit, and you're done. At least, on Win32 target.